Discount on google play store in-app product
i have 1 app on google play store and on app store. There are some product exist on app to sell. Now i like to give some discount using promo code. i am using google play store and app store payment gateway to handle payment mechanism. Product price is coming from google play store and app store. now my question is how i can manage discount mechanism.

Please visit this tour page before composing a question here in SO. Since you're talking about development matters, ask here instead: Software Engineering StackExchange.
